# How to replace value in each field until a certain character in each record?

Tags: awk, sed, replace

Each record coming with column names. I have to replace them in each record as shown below:

```
TIME=20181219110000275|CHAN=FMBKHJBAAAADPCFNAAAAAABA|EVNT=SWIgrld|API=SWIrecGrammarActivate|TYPE=uri/2.0|URI=http://media-elr/en-us/grammar/PRVS05/PRVS_param_gram.grxml?SWI.appsessionid=00053050771545238465&SWI.appstepid=1|WGHT=1|PROPS=inet.timeoutDownload=5000;inet.timeoutIO=5000;inet.timeoutOpen=5000;inet.urlBase=http://vxml3-elr:7000/CVP/;swirec_language=en-US|FETCHES=0|MEMHITS=1|MEMMISS=0|DISKHITS=0|DISKMISS=0|LDCPU=0|LDTIME=1|GCCPU=0|GCTIME=0|IFCPU=0|IFTIME=0|IFBYTES=0|COMPILES=0|RC=0|UCPU=186093|SCPU=30828
```

Output should look like:

```
20181219110000275|FMBKHJBAAAADPCFNAAAAAABA|SWIgrld|SWIrecGrammarActivate|uri/2.0|http://media-elr/en-us/grammar/PRVS05/PRVS_param_gram.grxml?SWI.appsessionid=00053050771545238465&SWI.appstepid=1|1|inet.timeoutDownload=5000;inet.timeoutIO=5000;inet.timeoutOpen=5000;inet.urlBase=http://vxml3-elr:7000/CVP/;swirec_language=en-US|0|1|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|186093|30828
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
  string='abc=something|efgh=anotherThing|klmnop=yet_another_thing'
  string='|'$string    #to prepend with '|' and have a pattern
  result=$( echo "$string" | sed 's/|[a-zA-Z]*=/|/g' )
  result=${result:1}   # remove the leading '|' we added

  something|anotherThing|yet_another_thing
```